# Elasticsearch range filter not working (No filter registered for)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying ta add a range filter to my search (only articles with workflow status <= 5 should appear) and getting errors
what's wrong with my range?

```
    $searchParams = array(
        'index' => $config->search->index,
        'type' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'size' => 10,
        'from' => ($page - 1) * 10,
        'body' => array(
            'query' => array(
                'filtered' => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        'multi_match' => array(
                            'query' => $query,
                            'fields' => array('title^8', 'caption^5', 'teasertext^4', 'articletext^2') // ^x = Gewichtung des Felds
                        ),
                    ),
                    'filter' => array(
                        'bool' => array(
                            'must' => array(
                                'term' => array(
                                    'deleted' => 0,
                                    'visible' => 1
                                ),
                                'range' => array(
                                    'workflow_status' => array('lte' => '5')
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'sort' => array('_score', '_id:desc')
```

here my mapping for status:

```
"workflow_status": {
                    "type":  "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error? (asking for it because you "query" is in php, but the error should show part of the actual query reaching ES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not a valid Query DSL , must should take in an array.
The body should be something on these lines :

```
body =>
    array(
        'query' => array(
        'filtered' => array(
            'query' => array(
                'multi_match' => array(
                    'query' => $query,
                    'fields' => array('title^8', 'caption^5', 'teasertext^4', 'articletext^2') // ^x = Gewichtung des Felds
                ),
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                'bool' => array(
                    'must' => array(
                        array(
                            'term' => array(
                                'deleted' => 0
                            )
                        ),
                        array('term' => array(
                            'visible' => 1
                            )
                        ),
                        array(
                            'range' => array(
                                'workflow_status' => array('lte' => '5')
                            )
                        )
                    )
```